# strimzi heath check 404 at health/liveness

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

I am not terribly familiar with the platform at this point, so please bear with me.
My devops team has set up kafka connect service instances in docker containers in k8s using strimzi .
The connect services seem to run OK, but they are constantly (every 30 seconds) logging this error:

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:542)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:318)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:365)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:392)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:679)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:250)
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
Uncaught exception in REST call to /health/liveness (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.ConnectExceptionMapper)
```

The team that set it up has told me they can't figure out how to fix it. It does not seem to be doing much harm, but I am not happy with 1) the log clutter and 2) something just obviously being mis-configured in the services.
I looked through the docs some, but TBH, I am a bit lost at this point.

If anyone is familiar with this behavior, can you point me to a reference of how to fix this?
Thanks,
JS

Comment: I think you need to configure healthcheck. Please see [docs](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/master/using.html#ref-healthchecks-deployment-configuration-kafka) for details

Comment: Thank you,  I knew about the docs, as I mentioned in my post. However, as also mentioned, I was unable to determine an answer to my problem from them. I was hoping someone can help with a more detailed answer.